# How to get all combinations of length 3

Tags: permutation

My problem is to get the list of all combinations of length 3 where the first place can be 1,2; second place could be a,b; third place could be 1,2,3,4. So the output is should be like this:
$\{\{1,a,1\},\{1,a,2\},\cdots,\{2,b,4\}\}$.

Comment: Look up `Tuples`.

Comment: `Distribute` is another possibility.  `Distribute[{{1, 2}, {a, b}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, List] == 
 Tuples[{{1, 2}, {a, b}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]` => True

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use `Tuples`

```
Tuples[{{1, 2}, {a, b}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]
```

Does what you want. Check out the documentation.

Cheers

Comment: Yes it does the job, thanks! Could you please explain the rule a bit, like if I had length $n$, the first place has $K_1$ possibilities, 2nd place $K_2$ possibilities,...,$n$-th place $K_n$ possibilities?

Comment: Aha sorry got it now. Thanks again!